# Phoenix changeset error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am confused about this phoenix behavior. It is an umbrella project with two applications: lib and web. Here is the umbrella mix.config:

```
defp deps do
[{:phoenix, "~> 1.2.1"},
 {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
 {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.6"},
 {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0"},
 {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
 {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
 {:lib, in_umbrella: true}
]
```

end

There is a simple `new.html.eex` file which is form that makes post to this controller function:

```
  def create(conn, %{"list" => list}) do
    changeset = List.changeset(%List{}, list)

    # BLOCK 1
    # case Repo.insert changeset do
    #   {:ok, %{id: id}} -> redirect conn, to: list_path(conn, :show, id)
    #   {:error, reasons} -> render conn, "new.html", changeset: reasons
    # end

    # BLOCK 2
    case ListQuery.create changeset do
      {:ok, %{id: id}} -> redirect conn, to: list_path(conn, :show, id)
      {:error, reasons} -> render conn, "new.html", changeset: reasons
    end
  end
```

//ListQuery.create

```
def create(list) do
  Repo.insert(list)
end
```

If I submit the blank form (invalid) while BLOCK 2 is uncommented as shown, none of the case patterns are matched and phoenix debug error page is shown.

If uncomment BLOCK 1 (and comment BLOCK 2), the error pattern is matched and I see the new.html.eex template rendered with error messages on the form.

Can someone please explain why the patterns are ignored if ListQuery.create is used?

Thanks

Comment: This shouldn't be happening with the code that you have shown. The easiest thing to do would be to call and output the value of `ListQuery.create(change)` and see what it is.

Comment: It should works... Also- why you want to wrap Repo functions inside other functions?

Comment: @PatNowak Query and command functions are abstracted into that module for testing mainly and for cleaner code.

Comment: Still, this code should work :D

Comment: @JustinWood Since the project is an umbrella, I didn't realize that changes in lib is not picked by phoenix.server. Umbrella needed to be recompiled. In summary, code works... Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @sheldon_cooper run the server at the root of the umbrella. The changes in your other applications will be recompiled.

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks @JustinWood

Comment: @sheldon_cooper - Please post an answer and accept it for others to see the solution more easily.